# Conditional aggregate database queries and their performance implications

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, performance, t-sql

I think this question is best asked with an example: if you want two counts from a table - say one with all the rows with a bit flag set to false and another with all of the ones set to true - is there a best practice for this kind of query and what are the performance implications of any approaches that could be taken?

To expand a little, and basing it off of the article below, how would separate queries compare to the version with the `CASE` evaluation in the `SELECT` list from a performance point of view? Are there other methods?

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/310674/Conditional-Sums-in-SQL-Aggregate-Methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than Blam's way, I think there are three basic ways to get the desired result. I tested the three options below as well as Blam's on my system. The results I found were as follows. Also, a side note, we didn't have any bit data in our system so I counted an indexed column with two values ("H" or "R").

Using Conditional Aggregates method resulted in the fastest performance. Using Blam's Grouping with an Aggregate method resulted in the second fastest way, consistently taking about 33% longer than the Conditional Aggregates. The Two Separate Select Statements method was the third fastest, consistently taking close to 50% longer than the Conditional Aggregates. Finally, the Joins method took the longest, and was close to 1000% slower than the Conditional Aggregates. The joins were expected (by me) to take the longest as you're joining to that table multiple times. The reason I included this method is because it was not discussed (possibly for obvious reasons) in the question; all performance issues aside, it is a viable if not extremely slow option. The two separate select statements also makes sense as you're running two separate aggregates, accessing that table two separate times.

I'm not sure what accounts for the differences between the conditional aggregate method and Blam's method. I've always been pleasantly surprised by the speed and performance of case statements, and today was no different.

I think the case statement method, aside from the performance considerations, is possibly the most versatile method. It allows you to work with just about any type of field and facilitates the selection of a subset of values, whereas Blam's Grouping with an Aggregate method would show all possible column values unless a Where clause were included.

**Conditional Aggregates**

```
Select SUM(Case When bitcol = 1 Then 1 Else 0 End) as True_Count
    , SUM(Case When bitcol = 0 Then 1 Else 0 End) as False_Count

From Table;
```

**Two separate select statements**

```
Select Count(1) as True_Count

From Table

Where bitcol = 1;

Select Count(1) as False_Count

From Table

Where bitcol = 0;
```

**Using Joins**

```
Select Count(T2.bitcol) as True_Count
    , Count(T3.bitcol) as False_Count

From Table T1
Left Outer Join Table T2
    on T1.ID = T2.ID
Left Outer Join Table T3
    on T1.ID = T3.ID;
```

Comment: Not seeing what your are seeing. Is it indexed?  What are the query plans?  I hold with don't think you can do better than a scan and a stream aggregate.

Comment: Yes, it is indexed. As for execution plans, unfortunately, I don't have access to those (I know, it's crazy). Besides, if it's indexed, it's not doing a scan. I don't know why it's showing up faster on my end, maybe it's a fluke or a problem on my end. I'm just reporting what I found.

Comment: Very interesting post, does anybody else have any evidence to confirm or refute the performance you were seeing?

Comment: I am looking at the query plan and yes it is an index scan.  How are you measuring performance?

Comment: Observed execution time in milliseconds.

Comment: How did you "observe"?  Did you clear the cache?  Was a network involved?  Was there other load on the server?   I tested on the server with no other users and mine was .4 seconds compared to case second at .7 seconds on a table with 1.4 million rows.

Comment: If you've already done the legwork on your end then put the data you got into your answer. You still never really answered his question in your answer. He asked for performance considerations. I put in my findings (as good/bad or objective/biased as they may be), so add your findings to your answer.

Comment: SO is for specific programming questions not performance implications.  I am OK with you exploring  performance implications but you called out my answer as not the most performant and I defended it.

Comment: @Blam My specific question was about the performance of various techniques, where do the SO guidelines say that it isn't for that? Your answer needs modification (a PIVOT) in order to return data in the same way as the other techniques (as columns instead of rows). How that would affect performance needs to be explored before it satisfies my question.

Comment: @ChristopherBrown I'm accepting your answer, thanks for the effort you put into your testing. Even if it is something situational about your server/data it is a good reminder that there is no better way of deciding what method to use than real-world use than testing on the actual data the query will be working with.

Comment: @Polynomial In the help  http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  Bullet 1 a specific programming problem

Comment: @Polynomial A general discussion on performance factors is not appropriate for this site.

Comment: @Polynomial Performance implications of any approaches is not one thing.  Any is not a specific thing?  Best practice for this kind of query is one thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT [bitCol], count(*)
  FROM [table]
 GROUP BY [bitCol]
```

If that column is indexed it is an index scan followed by a stream aggregate.
Doubt you can do better than that

Comment: Perhaps my example was too simple, but if you need more conditional aggregates then the results are rows rather than columns. I know you can fix that with a `PIVOT`, but how expensive are they from a performance point of view? I don't know what a `PIVOT` does under the hood, as it were. How would data set size factor into this?

Comment: That is my answer to the question as stated and I hold by that answer.